# Error create @Bean of ObjectMapper in @Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-databind

i have this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper obMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }

}
```

And this in my service:

```
@Qualifier("obMapper")
private ObjectMapper obMapper;
```

But i recieve this error:

```
Parameter 0 of method jacksonCodecCustomizer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.codec.CodecsAutoConfiguration$JacksonCodecConfiguration required a single bean
```

How should i create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to inject the bean you have to use one of these:

**1. Autowire the dependency**

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("obMapper")
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

**2. Use setter injection**

```
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
@Autowired
public setObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
}
```

You can find more details for example in [this article on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire).